# How to pass parameter has http headers into angular application

Tags: angular

Let's say I am opening angular application on some web application as hyperlink.  Let's say I want pass some value to angular as http header or form data. I should be able to access data in angular applications as well.  Here I am not referring  http api calls which we will be performing in angular applications(http interceptor).